# Generate Programs in Increasing size

Tags: code-golf, sequence, quine, code-generation

In this challenge, you will write a program which outputs a program which is the **double** the length of the original program. The outputted program should output a new program a program double *its* length.

### Examples

If my program is `a`:

```
< a
> aa

< aa
> aaaa

< aaaa
> aaaaaaaa
```

### Rules

- No quine built-ins
- The original program must be at least one byte
- The sequence should theoretically work infinitely
- Your program is not allowed to read from anything (file, stdio)

Your score is the size of the original program.

Comment: How about accessing the file by reading itself/accessing the place where the code is contained?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ that's not allowed as that would violate  rules I believe.

Comment: It's not a quine built-in. e.g. `document.getElementById("code")` or something.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ oh whoops, I left out a few words :| I meant to say "that would violate our quine rules, I believe"

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't think this was a quine challenge.

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ the quine rules are recommended by the tag wiki but don't apply automatically

Comment: I accidentally wrote a program that did this while working on the growing quine challenge

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21831/program-that-creates-larger-versions-of-itself-quine-variant

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/31529/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/39872/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37755/8478)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
{"_~"+_}_~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%22_~%22%2B_%7D_~)

#### Explanation

```
{"_~" e# Generalised quine framework, leaves the block and the string "_~"
      e# on the stack. 
+     e# Prepend the block to the string.
_     e# Duplicate the resulting array.
}_~
```

Comment: GolfScript isn't dead! [Ilmari has an answer to a similar question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21876/9498) that does this in exactly 10 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript, <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 37 bytes

Thanks to @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ for the help!

---

*Original [37 bytes]:*

```
f=_=>'f='+'_'.repeat((10+f).length)+f
```

*Child [74 bytes]:*

```
f=______________________________________=>'f='+'_'.repeat((10+f).length)+f
```

*Grandchild [148 bytes]:*

```
f=________________________________________________________________________________________________________________=>'f='+'_'.repeat((10+f).length)+f
```

---

**Alternate (with printing to console, and as a full program):**

*Original [61 bytes]:*

```
f=_=>console.log(`f=${'_'.repeat((0+f).length+5)+f};f()`);f()
```

*Child [122 bytes]:*

```
f=______________________________________________________________=>console.log(`f=${'_'.repeat((0+f).length+5)+f};f()`);f()
```

*Grandchild [244 bytes]:*

```
f=________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________=>console.log(`f=${'_'.repeat((0+f).length+5)+f};f()`);f()
```

---

**How it works!**

**1.**   `f=_=>`   Define function f as `console.log(...)`

**2.**   `;f()`   Run function f.

**3.**   *(in function f)*

- `console.log(...)`   Print the following:

  - `f=`   literal text "f="
  - `${'_'.repeat((0+f).length+5)`   "_" repeated for the length of f, altered to account for characters not included in the stringification of f
  - `+f}`   The stringification of function f
  - `;f()`   literal text ";f()"

**Notes**

- `console.log` is necessary instead of `alert` because `alert` doesn't seem to play well with really long strings (at least on my machine/browser configuration)
- The `_`'s are inserted into the name of the (unused) parameter of function f, to ensure that they are included in the stringification of f.
- Main improvement (aside from getting rid of the `console.log`) of the first solution over the second: adding `10` to the function instead of `0` to cast it to string makes it one byte longer, eliminating the need to add 1 to the length afterwards, saving a byte.

Comment: `0+f` should also work to cast the function to a string

Comment: 48 bytes: `(f=_=>\`(f=${'_'.repeat((0+f).length+5)+f})()\`)()`

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Forgot that returning the result is usually acceptable. Will update.

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ Actually, since writing answers as functions is generally accepted, does the solution even have to call the function?

Comment: sure, you could do

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure the solution has to call the function because the quine function can't output anything by itself (without the call).

Answer (score 6):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
"66*2-rIDdr$O.
```

[Original](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%2266*2-rIDdr%24O%2E), [child](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%2266*2-rIDdr%24O%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E), [grandchild](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%2266*2-rIDdr%24O%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E%2E).

#### Explanation

```
"66*2-      $O.    Standard quine formulation

      r            Reverse stack
       I           Push length of stack
        D          Pop n and duplicate top of stack n times
         d         Duplicate top of stack
          r        Reverse stack
```

What the bit in between `r`s does is duplicate the ending period enough times to fulfill the doubling criterion. `.` is the "stop program" character, so the many periods at the end do nothing except be there.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 12 bytes

```
{"_~"1$1$}_~
```

When run, this will print

```
{"_~"1$1$}_~{"_~"1$1$}_~
```

which, in turn, will print

```
{"_~"1$1$}_~{"_~"1$1$}_~{"_~"1$1$}_~{"_~"1$1$}_~
```

and so on.

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=eyJffiIxJDEkfV9-&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 51 bytes

```
x=r"print('x=r\"'+x+'\"'+';exec(x*2)');";exec(x*2)
```

This includes a trailing newline.

Which outputs:

```
x=r"print('x=r\"'+x+'\"'+';exec(x*2)');";exec(x*2)
x=r"print('x=r\"'+x+'\"'+';exec(x*2)');";exec(x*2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 11 bytes

```
{: ".~"]}.~
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=ezogIi5-Il19Ln4&input=)

#### How the source code works

```
{: ".~"]}.~

{       }    Define and push a code block.
         .~  Push a copy and execute it.
 :           Save the code block in the space character.
             Every subsequent space will now execute the code block.
   ".~"      Push that string.
       ]     Wrap the entire stack in an array.
```

If the above source code is executed once, the stack will end up as

```
["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]
```

where the empty string at the beginning corresponds to the initial state of the stack (empty input).

Two copies of the source code would leave a final state of

```
[["" {: ".~"]} ".~"] {: ".~"]} ".~"]
```

and so on.

#### What happens next

After executing the source code, the interpreter does the following:

1. It wraps the entire stack in an array, and pushes that array on the stack.

   For a single copy of the source code, the stack now contains

   ```
   ["" {: ".~"]} ".~"] [["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]]
   ```
2. It executed `puts` with the intention of printing the wrapped stack, followed by a linefeed.

   `puts` is defined as `{print n print}`, so it does the following.

   1. `print` prints the wrapped up copy of the stack without inspecting it (i.e., without converting it to its string representation). This sends

      ```
      {: ".~"]}.~
      ```

      to STDOUT and pops the stack copy from the top of the stack.

      The stack now contains

      ```
      ["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]
      ```
   2. executes the code block we defined previously.

      `:` begins by saving `["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]` in the space character, then `".~"` pushes itself and `]` wraps the stack in an array.
   3. `n` pushes a string consisting of a single linefeed.

      The stack now contains

      ```
      [["" {: ".~"]} ".~"] ".~"] "\n"
      ```
   4. is executed once more. However, it was redefined when we called it for the first time and now contains an array, not a code block.

      In fact, it pushes `["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]`, leaving the stack as

      ```
      [["" {: ".~"]} ".~"] ".~"] "\n" ["" {: ".~"]} ".~"]
      ```
   5. Finally, `print` prints the topmost stack item without inspecting it, sending

      ```
      {: ".~"]}.~
      ```

      to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1):

## , 26 chars / 36 bytes

```
⟮ô`\u27ee⦃ᶈ0}\u27ef
`ď2)⟯
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%9F%AE%C3%B4%60%5Cu27ee%E2%A6%83%E1%B6%880%7D%5Cu27ef%0A%60%C4%8F2%29%E2%9F%AF%0A)</kbd>

Note that there is a trailing newline.

## Explanation

Standard quine: `⟮ⒸⅩ222+ᶈ0`

Modifications:

- Use `ô` function to output the quines all results instead last result (as done using implicit output)
- Use `\u27ee⦃ᶈ0}\u27ef\n` and close copy block to prevent conflicts with later copy blocks.
- Use `ď2` to repeat string twice.