# Continuously expanding code

Tags: code-golf, quine

Your job is to write a program that rewrites and makes itself longer on each run of the program.

## Challenge

The program will print `Hello, World!\n` (`\n` denotes a newline). Then, it will modify its own file so that the new program length is exactly 2x the length at runtime. This modified file when run, will print `Hello, World!\nHello, World!\n`. When run a third time, the file will print `Hello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!\nHello, World!\n`.

More simply, on the `n`th run of the program, it will output `2^(n-1)` instances of `Hello, World!\n`, and have a program length of `2^(n-1)` the length of the original.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code (before first run) wins. Please comment if you need something is not clear.

**Edit:** To get past the restriction of file-rewriting, your program may print the modified source along with the `Hello, World!\n`s at a **+40%** penalty.

Comment: "it will modify its own file" can you provide a way to circumvent this?

Comment: What do you mean by `circumvent`?

Comment: Well, we can't exactly modify our own file in online compilers...

Comment: @KennyLau How about printing something that theoretically would work offline?

Comment: Please don't create arbitrary tags... A discussion for this tag has already happened [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5269/32686) (but this discussion was about a subset of KOTH challenges so might not be completely relevant here) and it was decided NOT to add [tag:self-rewriting] as a new tag, partially due to it being to narrow

Comment: @LegionMammal978 it's more like http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69504/8478 I guess.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Isn't that challenge about printing itself? This one isn't exactly that.

Comment: How is this an exact duplicate?

Comment: @ericw31415 Answers could be copied without much modification.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Really? None of those involve [tag:self-rewriting] though. Also, the output increases exponentially.

Comment: @ericw31415 It's the difference between `print("Hello, world!");print(quine(),quine());` and `print("Hello, world!");write(this_file(),quine(),quine());`

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Using, that though, on the 10th run, there will be 10 `Hello, World!`s, not 1024.

Comment: @ericw31415 `write(this_file(),quine(),quine());` duplicates the program; I'm assuming here that it doesn't append.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 100

### More efficient, 101

```
<?$a=$argv[0];$b=file_get_contents($a);file_put_contents($a,$b.substr($b,81,20));echo"Hello World\n";
```

This script is appending an `echo"Hello World";`, but because you said the size should also vary, and because it's shorter, I'm also having this script:

### Shorter, 100

```
<?$a=$argv[0];$b=file_get_contents($a);file_put_contents($a,$b.substr($b,2,98));echo"Hello World\n";
```

This script is appending itself, in a way it adds one Hello World, but this version will overall take more space and takes longer to execute.

### Example

But the scripts don't vary when it comes to the output:

```
root@raspberrypi:~/stack# php hello_expand.php
Hello World
root@raspberrypi:~/stack# php hello_expand.php
Hello World
Hello World
root@raspberrypi:~/stack# php hello_expand.php
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: Umm, the third run of the program should have 4 `Hello, Worlds!`, not 3.